# How to elegantly define a global types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type `type myObject = object;` that I would like to make available globally (to any module transpiled with tsc).
Is there an elegant way to define a global type (alias) in TypeScript?

Comment: You can define types in a `.d.ts` file, which makes the type available throughout your app

Comment: @Kokodoko And how does TypeScript now where this new file is located or in other words where does the file have to be stored?

Comment: If you use visual studio code, you can store the file anywhere in your project folder. The editor will read the file automatically.

Comment: I'm running the tsc cli from npm

Comment: `tsc` should also automatically pick up `.d.ts` files. But I assume you are coding inside a code editor, so there you can double-check if the `.d.ts` file works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a file with ending .d.ts that contains the type myObject = object; in a directory processed by tsc as described by Kokodoko works for me!

Comment: Maybe something has changed but this is *not* working for me: no matter how I refer to `myObject`, it has a type of `any`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it does not work for you, but the basic principle does: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wxitrh?file=index.ts